# Connecting two Arduinos via serial and using one to control the other

Tags: arduino

I'm a beginner with this stuff and I'm having a bit of a problem.  I've tried searching for an answer and I'm possibly wording my search wrong, but I can't find anything to help me out.

I'm looking to connect two Arduino Unos via the TX RX ports, and connect a bend sensor to one and an LED to the other.  I'm looking to make the LED fade up and down in relation to the bend sensor value.  I've got my code working so I can do it all on the one Arduino, but most of the things I've found while searching have been related to passing single characters via the RX TX ports and using the Arduino to connect to other things that aren't other Arduinos.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A more specific question would be helpful here?  What have you tried?  What isn't working?  Is passing a single byte value that indicate the bend sensor reading insufficient?

Answer (score 0):

you can use spi, or 2 wire!
here are some links:
spi - http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI
wire - http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire

wire might be more fitting for your situation?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I managed to get it sorted via the RX TX channels using Serial.write.